# Pentaho BI server access throwing quartz error

Tags: quartz-scheduler, pentaho

I recently installed Pentaho and I was able to access the BI server, however I made a few changes to get connected to mysql server and export databases, since then I am unable to access the BI server. I am getting the following error:

```
  2012-03-07 11:49:18,847 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.util.logging.Logger]  misc-org.pentaho.platform.scheduler.QuartzSystemListener: QuartzSystemListener.ERROR_0001 -     Scheduler was not properly initialized at startup
org.quartz.SchedulerConfigException: Failure occured during job recovery. [See nested   exception: org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't clean volatile data: Table      'quartz.QRTZ_FIRED_TRIGGERS' doesn't exist [See nested exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table ' quartz.QRTZ_FIRED_TRIGGERS' doesn't exist]]
```

Also while stopping the server I get the following exception:

```
 java.sql.SQLException: socket creation error
 java.sql.SQLException: socket creation error
```

Answer (score 2):

By "made a few changes to get connected to mysql server", I expect you mean that you made the BI Server point at MySQL instead of HSQLDB.

I'm guessing that you either didn't change the SQL dialect setting for the quartz database connection, or Quartz doesn't actually create the schema it depends on (in which case you'll have to copy it over from hsqldb to mysql)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running the scripts located in `[/path/to/biserver-ce/data]` to generate the tables for the database you are using?